# How to store fingerprint2 result in a var

Tags: javascript

I'm tying to store fingerprint2 result in a var.

```
var info = {};
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
  info.fingerprint = result;
});
alert(info.fingerprint);
```

but not work
is there a better way like:

```
var fp = new Fingerprint2().get();
```

or some enhanced method?

edited :
Modern & flexible browser fingerprinting library, a successor to the original fingerprintjs http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs2/

Usage:

```
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
  console.log(result); //a hash, representing your device fingerprint
  console.log(components); // an array of FP components
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is not working as expected because `Fingerprint2().get(...)` is asynchronous - that means that `alert(info.fingerprint)` will run *before* the callback function passed to `get` has finished.

To understand why this is necessary if you don't understand the concept of asynchonicity, take a look at the [demo page](http://valve.github.io/fingerprintjs2/). You'll see that it says how long it takes to calculate the fingerprint. You `alert` will be run between when `get` is called and when the has been calculated, and therefore cannot know what the fingerprint will be.

The only time that you can guarantee that you have the fingerprint is during the callback function.

```
var info = {};

new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
    info.fingerprint = result;

    afterFingerprintIsCalculated();
});

function afterFingerprintIsCalculated() {
    alert(info.fingerprint);
}



// BETTER (no global state)
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components) {
    var info = {
        fingerprint: result
    };

    processFingerprint(info);
});

function processFingerprint(data) {
    alert(data.fingerprint);
}
```

Comment: alert() is example in my code , i want to store it in var an use it in my javascript code. how to store it in var secure

Comment: The same rules apply - it's fine to use it in a variable, but *only after* the function inside `get` has run. See the top example - it's safe to read from the info variable inside `afterFingerprintIsCalculated` - so you can put the code which needs to read from it in there.

Comment: is there a way to store it and use out side function? my code shouldn't run in that function because i have some othe vars @iblamefish

Comment: is it possible to store fingerprint2 result in a var and use it every where?@iblamefish

Comment: @MohammadAlipour yes, as long as "everywhere" means within the callback function (or any other functions which it then calls). *There is no way to get around this being asynchronous code*.

Comment: demo link is broken